# Python: How to import by name

Tags: python, import

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
  from SettingsHandler import YamlParser
  from UIComponents.IncrementSlider import IncrementSlider
  from UIComponents.ToggleSwitch import ToggleSwitch
  from UI.SettingsPane import SettingsPane
  #from KeyStrokeWrapper import KeyStrokeWrapper
else:
  from Handlers.SettingsHandler import YamlParser
  from Handlers.KeyStrokeWrapper import KeyStrokeWrapper
  from Handlers.UIComponents.IncrementSlider import IncrementSlider
  from Handlers.UIComponents.ToggleSwitch import ToggleSwitch
  from Handlers.UI.SettingsPane import SettingsPane
```

This is starting to get rediculous, how do I import by only file name?

eg: import IncrementSlider rather than from Handlers.UIComponents.IncrementSlider import IncrementSlider

Comment: Your `if` / `else` is an indicator of a bad project structure. The scripts you execute should always be in the project's root, or handle the `PYTHONPATH` themselfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional import makes me think that something is wrong. You should have a toplevel package such as:

```
MyEpicPackage
- __init__.py
- Handlers
  - __init__.py
  - more_files.py
- another_sub_package
  - __init__.py
  - more_files.py
```

Rather than relative importing, just import everything from your package from inside the package, *without bothering with relative imports*: `from MyEpicPackage import Handlers`, `from MyEpicPackage.subpackage.file import MyClass`, etc.

---

If this still doesn't work, use `importlib.import_module`:

```
import_module(name, package=None)
    Import a module.
    The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
    specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
    relative import to an absolute import.
```

The package will be your toplevel package, which needs `__init__.py`.

Comment: I see it's probably supposed to be ok but I run the unit testing straight from the file, perhaps I should run it from the main directory?

Comment: Wouldn’t you put tests in a tests folder inside the package? You can still import the package itself and the contents.

Comment: alright yeah, I refactored and it seems to work without the conditionals. It seems to have fixed the issue. I think before I just had a really bad project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say `import X`, where X is that file or module name, and from there if you have to refer to specific things, just say "X.YYY", where Y is that specific thing. You do this when you say

```
from Handlers.SettingsHandler import YamlParser
```

Make sure that if you import a folder, that folder has an `__init__.py` file there.
Let me know how that works!

Comment: i got relative module names are not supported

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer or a solution, rather a similar situation that I had.

I've had a similar problem with scrapy framework, where I repeated `from x import`  like 7 times. I solved that by changing the PYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the directory where the modules were, but be careful! Because when I did that scrapy couldn't see its options.py file (which is not explicitly imported) so I had to change some variables related to scrapy from the shell.

Google how to change the PYTHONPATH environment variable for your OS. I would also recommend using a virtual environment before doing that, to avoid messing your python system-wide.